# Go and into the jump, meaning?

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand what does "Go and into" mean here. The frame is approximately this one: there's a skater getting her trainings in front of a TV camera (which is supposed to create media interest around her) and her trainer is inciting her to do some skating figures and moves. At a given point the trainer orders this: "Go and into the jump".

What does it mean here?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** Audio clip [here](https://instaud.io/3ASQ) ( the sentence in the title is at 00:40 ).

Comment: Are you sure it is not saying "Go and **enter** the jump", or "Go **on** into the jump"?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Completely, I copy-pasted the english subtitle.

Comment: Subtitles are often wrong. A link to the clip would help, with a time cue.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The movie is with english audio, I can confirm this is what is actually being said.

Comment: I ask because the phrase you wrote is meaningless.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I thought so too... in long time I've been into translation I've never found anything like this. I'll try to have a audio clip of this for a double check.

It could take some time...

Comment: Voting to close for lack of context.

Comment: @HotLicks Added pretty complete audio clip-

Comment: It is really indistinct, and in the background. The instructor is calling out to the student, perhaps "Spin, spin, come on, go, back, six, go, ten, into the jump."

Comment: @WeatherVane: Here is what I have: Come on, spin, spin! Come on, pull! That's it, go and into the jump.

Comment: It's just an indistinct set of instructions, not a sentence. It is certainly not an on-topic English question. Similarly: start, stop, go, pause, ready, into the jump.

Comment: It is just a question about the meaning of it, I mean, it cannot be just like picking some random words, there must be a meaning, so in my opinion it's not off-topic about "meaning" tag.

Comment: Heavens! It means "now go into the jump". The jump is a skating move, like the spin, the crouch, the lunge, etc. There was a pause, a comma if you like, after "go". As in "go, into the jump". Or "Go, and into the jump".

Comment: I transcribe it as "Go <slight pause> and <slight pause> into the jump". It's not a pattern. He's saying "Go", then he's saying "And" and then he's saying "Into the jump". He's not trying to say full complete coherent sentences.

Comment: Mitch has it right.  The trainer is just talking the skater through a jump giving timely cues as the move is executed.

Comment: In this series of instructions, *go* = "continue"; *and* = "moving on to the next part of the routine"; *into* = "start executing"; and *the jump* means "the action that involves flexing the leg muscles to impart sufficient momentum for the skater to temporarily leave the surface of the skating rink".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "into the jump" is analogous to  Henry V in Shakespeare: "Once more unto the breach," or the song title "Once more into the fray."  The *unto* or *into* expresses commitment.

"to be into" is defined thus, at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/be-into:

> be into
>
> Also, get into . Be interested in or involved with. For example, She's
>   really into yoga , or Once you retire, it's important to get into some
>   hobby you've always wanted to try . [ Colloquial ; mid-1900s]

I could say, about skiing, "I was into the turn before I realized my weight was to far back."  There are some things to which one needs to make a commitment, like jumping a ditch, rather than going tentatively step by step.